# Facebook graph API App stats and rate limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am starting to use graph API for a specific application deployed on server side (not using mobile or web SDK).
I read the official documentation about the rate limit usage:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

I did some requests using Graph API Explorer and a dedicated client in Java - approximately 50-80 calls.

Today from App stats dashobard I have seen that I did 410 calls.
Can you help me to understand the reason?

I used the API just to do this kind of call:
me/feed with specific fields.

I didn't use the API with specific object ID or multiple object ID.

Thanks a lot

Bye

Comment: The API Explorer does a bunch of behind-the-scenes calls to get tokens, lists of available pages, etc. I wonder if your JavaClient does some sort of retry or pagination logic, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
No, at the moment we tried just to do a very simple call with a java client (and Graph Explorer) on a page within just 4 posts and some comments.
There isn't any pagination or logic implemented.